# FTP passive mode connection refused

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

I'm creating an **ftp client** and I have a problem.

First, I create a socket where I sent USER and PASS then PASV a receive IP and PORT and then create a second data socket and try to connect, but there is a problem.

It will connect 5 times of 6, but on the 6th time I got error `111 Connection Refused` and I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response text to `PASV` does not have a standardized format ([`EPSV`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428#section-3) does, though), so make sure you are parsing the IP/Port correctly, as you may receive one of many different formats used by real-world servers:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2).
227 Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2
227 Entering Passive Mode. h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2
227 =h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2
```

Just to show a few possibilities.

If you are parsing the IP/Port correctly and still not able to connect, then either the server has too many client connections on the IP/Port and ran out of available slots for you to connect to, or else the IP/Port is being blocked by a firewall/router that the server does not know about when it reported the IP/Port to you.

Unfortunately, a `connection refused` error does not offer any way to differentiate between those conditions, so all you can do is attempt to connect a few times before failing the transfer, or else send an `ABOR` to inform the server to close the current passive IP/Port and then send a new `PASV` to get a new IP/Port.

Comment: Im parsing correctly, because it will connect sometimes. Anyway Ill try that ABOR.